# Why server no restarting after error in validation

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, joi

I am working with node.js and Graphql without Express, to validate the input i use Joi, so in my mutation resolver i did this:

```
 async user(_, { input }, { dataSources }) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      debug(input);
    }

    // Validation
    if (input.role === 'user') {
      debug('validate user creation schema');
      validate(userSchemas.userRegisterSchema.post, input);
    } else if (input.role === 'pro') {
      debug('validate pro creation schema');
      validate(userSchemas.userProRegisterSchema);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Bad input error');
    }
```

so this is the code in the validate function folder:

```
import Debug from 'debug';
import BadInputError from '../errors/BadInputError.js';
/*
* validate module.
* @module validate
*/
const debug = Debug(`${process.env.DEBUG_MODULE}:validation`);

// function to validate the input data
async function validate(schema, inputData) {
  try {
    debug('validate input data');
    await schema.validateAsync(inputData);
  } catch (error) {
    debug('validation error');
    throw new BadInputError(error);
  }
}

export default validate;
```

And when entry is wrong i have the error but server crash, i don't want server crash...
Have you an idea please?
thank you

i try a lot of things, with return and some idea of IA but nothing good.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to throw error from else condition.

```
throw new Error('Bad input error');
```

this error do not have any handling when the promise is rejected.
you can also use unhandledRejection event at process level if required.
https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-unhandledrejection

or else just log using your logger.

```
'Bad input error'
```

Comment: i tried that:

`process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    debug('Unhandled Rejection at:', promise, 'reason:', reason);
  }
  // Application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
});
// function to validate the input data
async function validate(schema, inputData) {
  debug('validate input data');
  await schema.validateAsync(inputData);
}

export default validate;`

Comment: that show the error but that don't stop the request... It's to register an user so if the validation fail that just stop the request with error (without crash the server), and if it's good the user is registered. With this code the user is registered even if it's a fail validation...?

Comment: how you are handling the request cycle then?
these handlings are done at the controller level which handles how the request is going to end. please share your sample code who's managing the incoming req.

Comment: I don't use controller because i 'am with graphql, so now i found how to use validation with custom scalars

Answer (score 0):

I found an other solution to validate with custom scalar,I found it complicated but through reflection I managed to implement it, which allows me to validate directly in the schemas, this the code :

```js
import { GraphQLScalarType, GraphQLError } from 'graphql';
import validator from 'validator';

const validateEmail = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'Email',
  description: 'Email custom scalar type',
  serialize(value) {
    // Validation during serialization
    if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
      throw new GraphQLError('Invalid email address');
    }
    return value;
  },
  parseValue(value) {
    // Validation during value analysis
    if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
      throw new GraphQLError('Invalid email address');
    }
    return value;
  },
  parseLiteral(ast) {
    // Validation during AST analysis
    if (!validator.isEmail(ast.value)) {
      throw new GraphQLError('Invalid email address');
    }
    return ast.value;
  },
});

const validatePassword = new GraphQLScalarType({
  // minLength: 8, minLowercase: 1, minUppercase: 1, minNumbers: 1,
  // minSymbols: 1, returnScore: false, pointsPerUnique: 1,
  // pointsPerRepeat: 0.5, pointsForContainingLower: 10,
  // pointsForContainingUpper: 10, pointsForContainingNumber: 10,
  //  pointsForContainingSymbol: 10 }
  name: 'Password',
  description: 'Password custom scalar type',
  serialize(value) {
    // Validation during serialization
    if (!validator.isStrongPassword(value)) {
      throw new GraphQLError('Invalid password');
    }
    return value;
  },
  parseValue(value) {
    // Validation during value analysis
    if (!validator.isStrongPassword(value)) {
      throw new GraphQLError('Invalid password');
    }
    return value;
  },
  parseLiteral(ast) {
    // Validation during AST analysis
    if (!validator.isStrongPassword(ast.value)) {
      throw new GraphQLError('Invalid password');
    }
    return ast.value;
  },
});

export { validateEmail, validatePassword };
```

import on index.js fromresolvers:

```js
import { validateEmail, validatePassword } from '../validations/scalars.js';

export default {
  validateEmail,
  validatePassword,
  Query,
 };
```

and import in index.js on schemas:

```js
const schema = `#graphql
scalar validateEmail
scalar validatePassword
    ${Query}
    ${Mutation}
`;

export default schema;
```